# Can someone explain a part a small piece of Django code?

Tags: python, django

I was following this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone) and trying to implement a profile updating tool. One piece of code they provided was as follows:

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

I managed to work out what all of meant apart from the line

```
return redirect('settings:profile')
```

After changing the variables, I get the error :

> NoReverseMatch at /profile/
>
> 'settings' is not a registered namespace

Do I need to create something else? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The blog you are following has not mentioned the urls.py file. You need to create a python file named **urls.py** and add `/profile` path in there

Comment: You can learn how to add urls in your app here [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect required your view name or some  url

Call like:-
redirect('profile')

profile define view name in your url file.

url like:-
path('profile', profileView, name='profile'),

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just changing the redirect to '/' but your explanation helped me understand.